# Combining react-native-reanimation code with styled component

Tags: styled-components, react-native-reanimated

I have styled my app with styled components I want to use reanimated to animate button and scroll view etc
I am having problems adding the animation to the styled components. Each works well individually but not together.

I'm pretty new with react-native...so I'm not sure if this is possible.

I have tried extending the component to the animated style
Adding Animated.StyledView to the line of code and adding inline animation styles as one would to a regular View

I have also tried nesting the styled component with Animation.View component...none of my solutions have worked so far...any suggestions??

I have found no solution online so far